# How to pass window.pageOffsetY value to a fixed var when scroll starts?

Tags: javascript

I'm using `window.pageYOffset` to get the scroll position on the page.
The thing is i want the scroll position to be passed into a var that i can reference to to know what was the scroll position when the user scrolled.

Whatever i do i can't manage to get a fixed var. Its always a reference to the value, constantly updating.

```js
(() => {
   const handler = () => {
      const offset = window.pageYOffset || window.scrollY;

      var focusedElement = header.querySelector('.focus');

      if ( focused ){
         var offsetWhenFocuseIsTrue = offset;
         console.log('the scroll pageOffset is '+ offsetWhenFocuseIsTrue);

         // what i want to do here is use the first value that was output so i can calculate if a certain element has been scrolled past
      }
   window.addEventListener('scroll', handler, false);
})();
```

So there you can probably guess what i'm trying to achieve. When the user scroll, nothing happens until focused is detected as defined and then i want to pass the value of offset at this moment. **I want a fixed value** but the console shows somthing like:

```
the scroll pageOffset is 322 navigation.js:225:13
the scroll pageOffset is 341 navigation.js:225:13
the scroll pageOffset is 372 navigation.js:225:13
the scroll pageOffset is 383 navigation.js:225:13
the scroll pageOffset is 392 navigation.js:225:13
the scroll pageOffset is 397 navigation.js:225:13
the scroll pageOffset is 399 navigation.js:225:13
the scroll pageOffset is 395 navigation.js:225:13
the scroll pageOffset is 368 navigation.js:225:13
the scroll pageOffset is 315 navigation.js:225:13
the scroll pageOffset is 281 navigation.js:225:13
the scroll pageOffset is 249 navigation.js:225:13
the scroll pageOffset is 216 navigation.js:225:13
the scroll pageOffset is 188 navigation.js:225:13
the scroll pageOffset is 37 navigation.js:225:13
```

Comment: remove the var from `var offsetWhenFocuseIsTrue` and add `var offsetWhenFocuseIsTrue;` outside the iife

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately it does work. The log output is the same as before. I edited the post with some more detail: what i want to do here is use the first value that was output so i can calculate if a certain element has been scrolled past

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to accomplish is to detect if an element was scrolled out of the view? Have you considered using the Intersection Observer API for this? (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Comment: very simply put i want a div to hide only on scroll but let the user the possibility to scroll if it does not appear entirely in small resolution for example. I had a "hideOnScroll" thing before but it was too strict. I did not know about this Observer API, i'm going to read about that. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @JonKoops the thing is my div is fixed that's why i can't really detect if it has been scrolled out of view!!